# Determining Exact Reason for Facebook Error Code 100

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-socialauth

I am experimenting with facebook and trying to create an event, via the Graph API. I am using django and the python-facebook-sdk from github. I can successfully post to my wall pull friends etc.

I am using django-social-auth for facebook login stuff and have settings.py for permissions:

```
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['publish_stream','create_event','rsvp_event']
```

In the graph api explorer on facebook my request works so I know what parameters to use and, well, I am using them.

Here is my python code:

```
def new_event(self):
    event = {}
    event['name'] = name
    event['privacy'] = 'OPEN'
    event['start_time'] = '2011-11-04T14:42Z'
    event['end_time'] = '2011-11-05T14:46Z'

    self.graph.put_object("me", "events", args=None, post_args=event)
```

The code that is calling the facebook api is roughly: (also the `access_token` is added to the `post_args` which then is converted to `post_data` and urlencoded.

```
    file = urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?" +
                          urllib.urlencode(args), post_data)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception Value: (#100) Invalid parameter
```

I am trying to figure out what is wrong, but am also curios of how to figure out overall what is wrong so I can debug this in the future. it seems to be too generic of an error because I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: A python error or facebook graph api error? Can you post more of the trace if it's the former

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690971/how-to-add-a-facebook-event-with-new-graph-api ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how `post_args` works but this call did the trick

`graph.put_object("me","events",start_time="2013-11-04T14:42Z", privacy="OPEN", end_time="2013-11-05T14:46Z", name="Test Event")`

The invalid parameter most likely is pointing to how you are feeding the parameters as post_args. I don't think the SDK was ever designed to feed it like this. I could be mistaken as I'm not really sure what `post_args` would be doing.

Another way based on how `put_object` is setup with `**data` it would be

```
graph.put_object("me","events", **event)
```